# Are there any recordings of Grothendieck online?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, online-resources, manuscript

Illusie [mentions](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~mitya/langlands/Illusie.wav) tape recordings of Grothendieck explaining his trace formula and more. Are they or similar recordings online? I guess, even if (what I doubt) everything he thought about that is somewhere in print, it would give an interesting insight in his way of thinking.

Comment: Despite the question mark at the end, I don't see what the question is. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: This seems like a real question to me: Are there any audio copies of Grothendieck's lectures, and can they be found online? 

Comment: I would rephrase the question as: I hear there are recordings of Grothendieck speaking. Are they online somewhere? Are there transcriptions online?

Comment: I agree that this is a real question, even though it doesn't read like one.

Comment: Q. just reformulated, I hope now clearer.

Comment: This is unrelated, strictly speaking, to the existence of tapes, but the oft-mentioned collection of manuscripts is now on the Grothendieck Circle, or for a direct link: https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Illusie told me last year that these tapes of his meetings with Grothendieck are somewhere in his basement where they're very hard to find, so they're certainly not online.

The recording of Illusie's reminisces of Grothendieck to which both posts link has been transcribed [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~tp/main.dvi). Drinfeld and Illusie will be releasing a more polished version at some point next year.

Comment: Thanks. Let's hope that they get secured and copied sometime before they deteriorate.  

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the transcriptions is broken.

Answer (score 23):

Will we continue Scientific Research
http://cds.cern.ch/record/912518?ln=en
Allons nous continuer la Recherche Scientifique
Recording number CERN-AUDIO-1972-003
Speaker(s) Grothendieck,A
Date 27 January 1972
Duration 138 minutes
Language French
Keywords Science
Synopsis Réflexions sur la science- responsabilité du savant
Copyright © 1972 CERN
Notes partie 1: exposé partie 2: questions f/a partie 3: questions f/a
Listen to Part 1: Part 2: Part 3:

100 hours of audio of lectures of Grothendieck
http://www.archmathsci.org/catalogue/general-chronology-of-recordings-since-1973/chronology-of-recordings-1973-1980/1973-recordings/
1973 Recordings
Lecture Courses by Alexandre GROTHENDIECK
3 Lecture Courses on respectively
1. Algebraic Geometry
2. The Theory of Algebraic Groups
3. Topos Theory

The copyright of all these recordings is that of the Department of
Mathematics of SUNY at Buffalо.

Comment: Not available as of now. Was it before ?

Comment: Not available but there is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323020459/http://www.archmathsci.org/catalogue/general-chronology-of-recordings-since-1973/chronology-of-recordings-1973-1980/1973-recordings/), and you can hear a part of this from the 18th minute in the talk [Un topo sur les topos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFV4FpfdwEw) by Alain Connes.
                <span class="d-none">$\endgro

Answer (score 9):

Now you can access the audio lectures that Grothendieck gave at Buffalо in 1973.

Lectures on Topoi

Algebraic geometry

Algebraic groups

[Thèmes pour une Harmonie](https://agrothendieck.github.io/)

In the section **1973**.

The page is still work in progress.

Comment: For instance, https://www.drive.google.com/file/d/1LyxcdFUj6LWcCTVqa_-pJpDPxmG_aemr/edit (see https://github.com/agrothendieck/agrothendieck.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a recording of Illusie talking about Grothendieck at [The Grothendieck circle](http://www.grothendieckcircle.org/).
I couldn't find any recordings of Grothendieck himself.